# How I can retrive "Community" metadata in Salesforce

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder

How I can retrieve "Community" metadata in Salesforce and will make to deploy for example to QA org. Need I create community/site in QA with equal site name how in DevOrg before deployment?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers for your questions first.

> How I can retrieve "Community" metadata in Salesforce and will make to
>   deploy for example to QA org

**depends on which deployment tool r u using?**

--if you using change set just follow "community deployment by change set" below link

-- by sfdx you have to create package.xml as below code snippet then retrieve by using sfdx command

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest manifest\package.xml  -u source org
```

> Need I create community/site in QA with equal site name how in DevOrg
>   before deployment?.

---yes you have to create Community with same name in your target org before deployment.

**My very rough notes below:**

Community metadata deployment is not straightforward like others. some of the things you need to do in manually in target org like (publish & assign audiences). for community deployment you have to follow the order strictly other wise it 'll get errors keep on.

--if your using change set deployment, Network is main key metadata component for choose.[community deployment by change set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_changesets.htm&type=5)

-- if you want deploy by SFDX you have to follow below steps.

1. first deployed the Community's Apex framework like(objects,fields,lightning components,apex classes/triggers)
2. and then the Network/CustomSite/SiteDotCom metadata,
3. and finally the Branding and Content Asset metadata

your package.xml should be like below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>DSN</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>DSN</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>DSN_C</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>A_Faculty</members>
        <members>B_Faculty</members>
        <members>C_Faculty</members>
        <name>Audience</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>cbDSN_Community</members>
        <name>NetworkBranding</name>
    </types>    
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks for the open answer. Can I deploy metadata from DevOrg to DevOrg or I can only from sandbox to prodactionOrg?

Comment: yes you can deploy metadata again which deployment tool?  by sfdx command 'sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi-community/unpackaged -u target-org`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Metadata developer guide for metadata names.

It would be `CommunityTemplateDefinition`.

You can refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitytemplatedefinition.htm for all the sub-metadata for community.