# Which metadata object stores NavigationMenu / TileMenu translations?

Tags: community-builder, translation-workbench, experience-cloud, navigation-menu, experience-bundle

Does anyone know which metadata object stores translations for the NavigationMenu component?  Specifically, I'm using a TileMenu component in the Community Builder.  The [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_tile_menu.htm&type=5) says to use Translation Workbench for Navigation Menu Item.  The translation works fine, I just need to deploy it.

I've checked the following metadata objects and can't find the translation: NavigationMenu, objectTranslations, ExperienceBundle, Translations.

I've also exported Language Content from the Community Builder > Setup > Languages and it wasn't there either.

Comment: Couldn't find it when testing either. There's no reference to NavigationMenu in [translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) and I'm not aware of any special metdadata types like CustomObjectTranslation that would hold this. The TileMenu does show up in `ExperienceBundle`, but there's no reference to translations within it (though it does contain languages enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the [NavigationMenuItemLocalization object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_navigationmenuitemlocalization.htm). You should be able to export / import the translation data thru data loader or equivalent tools.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

@David Cheng, please try the below based on the MetadataService class from Andrew Fawcett.

[How I can retrive "Community" metadata in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270984/how-i-can-retrive-community-metadata-in-salesforce)

`NetworkBranding` is a method in MetadataService.cls, so i searched for `NavigationMenu` and found a service method called as `NavigationMenuItem`. Check in the below git file link, line 11238.

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls

So your package.xml to retrieve/deploy should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>cbDSN_Community</members>
        <name>NavigationMenuItem</name>
    </types>    
    <version>46.0</version>
</Package>
```

Let me know if it helps!